# Import library or create object in middle of test case steps

Tags: python, robotframework

From what I can tell robotframework script can only import a python library at beginning of the script and the objects have to be created at start.  Is there a way to create new objects as in the middle of the test case steps?

The problem is that some of the argument values are not generated at start of the test.

Any advice?

Comment: creating objects and importing libraries are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `Import Library` keyword from BuiltIn library. Try to use it.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-import-library-keyword